# Attached NSMutableArray data in E-mail Body?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am New To Iphone programming.my Array store UIlabel along with properties.For Exp,Text,TextColor,background color etc.Now i want to send all the array data in E-mail body.
here is my code.

```
    NSUserDefaults *userDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myDecodedObject = [userDefault objectForKey: [NSString 
            stringWithFormat:@"sample"]];
    NSArray *arr= [[NSArray alloc] init];
    arr= [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myDecodedObject]; 
    NSString *string = [arr componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
    NSString *emailBody = string;
    NSLog(@"Testing %@", string);
    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
    [mailer release];
```

My array show all the objects which is store in it and also show bytes.At this time my array contain 5 UIlabel .Now i want to send all these UIlabel in E-mail body.but NSLog i see this.

Testing UILabel: 0x8123760; frame = (135.5 136; 99 30); text = 'Fddddddddddddddsaafgghjkl...'; clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; layer = CALayer: 0x8161590

UILabel: 0x81619b0; frame = (148 323; 69 15); text = 'Xxxxxxxxxxx'; clipsToBounds = YES; layer = CALayer: 0x8161a50

UILabel: 0x8161b70; frame = (140 341; 56 19); text = 'Xxxxxxx'; clipsToBounds = YES; layer = CALayer: 0x81618f0

UILabel: 0x8161d70; frame = (69.5 121.5; 99 145); text = 'Fddddddddddddddsaafgghjkl...'; clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; layer = CALayer: 0x8161e00

UILabel: 0x8161f10; frame = (108 321; 99 145); text = 'Fddddddddddddddsaafgghjkl...'; clipsToBounds = YES; layer = CALayer: 0x8161f80

Not Seen any data in E-mail.so please Suggest What is Best approach to send array data in E-mail.Thanx

Comment: Assuming `mailer` is correct, I would expect the same data in the body as what you see logged.  Can you show the result of `NSLog(@"mailer: %@", mailer);` just before the call to `setMessageBody`?  (Also `NSArray *arr= [[NSArray alloc] init];` is a leak.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I Attached NSMutableArray Data With E-mail Body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454185/how-can-i-attached-nsmutablearray-data-with-e-mail-body)

Comment: @PhillipMills when i use .NSLog(@"mailer: %@", mailer);i see this NSLog.mailer: <MFMailComposeViewController: 0x77660a0>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useMFmailComposer's addDataAttachements method to add the data from array

```
     NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arr1];
       NSLog(@"Testing %@", data);
      [controller addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/octet-stream";  
      fileName:nil]
```

Comment: @saad when i use above method i see this in NSlong..Testing <62706c69 73743030 d4010203 040508c9 ca542474 6f705824 6f626a65 63747358 24766572 73696f6e 59246172 63686976 6572d106 0754726f 6f748001 af102b09 0a143334 353d4445 4b4c5155 565d696a 6b6f7071 7d7e7f89 8a8e8f90 9e9fa0a6 a7abacad b9babbc1 c2c35524 6e756c6c d20b0c0d 135a4e53 2e6f626a 65637473 5624636c 617373a5 0e0f1011 12800280 0e801480 1c802480 2adf1010 15161718 191a1b1c 1d1e1f20 21220c23 24252627 28292a2b 24242e24 2a303132 5f100f55 49436c69 00020100 00000000 0000cb00 00000000 00000000 00000000 0005f1>

Comment: but not see any data in E-mail.